# Property 'uiSignal' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>

Tags: angular

I have upgraded my application from angular 4 to angular 6.

I am getting several errors like these saying Property uiSignal does not exist on Observable of type. The type would be number, string or any user defined object.  If you notice the Obserable.dts, it has uiSignal declared of type any. I suppose typescript is complaining because it cant determine the type. How do i resolve this issue

```
private _manageShare(sharingOptions: ISharingOptions) {
    const runId = sharingOptions.runId;
    this._runsProxy.manageShares(this._translate.instant('CURRENT_MODEL.TITLE'), runId, sharingOptions.changes)
      .uiSignal({ debugInfo: 'saving share', uiLabel: this._translate.instant('GLOBAL.BUSY.PERSISTING') })
      .subscribe(ret => {
        const runModel = this.runs.find(o => o.runId === runId);
        runModel.info.sharedWith = ret.data;
        const runName = runModel.info.name;

        this.calculatePages();
        this._sendAnalytics(runId, 'RunShareUpdated');
        this._alertService.success(this._translate.instant('RUN.SHARE.TOAST_MANAGE', { runName }));
      });
  }
```

Obserable.dts

```
import { Operator } from './Operator';
import { Subscriber } from './Subscriber';
import { Subscription } from './Subscription';
import { TeardownLogic, OperatorFunction, PartialObserver, Subscribable } from './types';
import { iif } from './observable/iif';
import { throwError } from './observable/throwError';
/**
 * A representation of any set of values over any amount of time. This is the most basic building block
 * of RxJS.
 *
 * @class Observable<T>
 */

export declare class Observable<T> implements Subscribable<T> {
    /** Internal implementation detail, do not use directly. */
    _isScalar: boolean;
    static uiSignal: () => any;
    /** @deprecated This is an internal implementation detail, do not use. */
    source: Observable<any>;
    /** @deprecated This is an internal implementation detail, do not use. */
    operator: Operator<any, T>;
    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param {Function} subscribe the function that is called when the Observable is
     * initially subscribed to. This function is given a Subscriber, to which new values
     * can be `next`ed, or an `error` method can be called to raise an error, or
     * `complete` can be called to notify of a successful completion.
     */
    constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic);
    /**
     * Creates a new cold Observable by calling the Observable constructor
     * @static true
     * @owner Observable
     * @method create
     * @param {Function} subscribe? the subscriber function to be passed to the Observable constructor
     * @return {Observable} a new cold observable
     * @nocollapse
     */
    static create: Function;
    /**
     * Creates a new Observable, with this Observable as the source, and the passed
     * operator defined as the new observable's operator.
     * @method lift
     * @param {Operator} operator the operator defining the operation to take on the observable
     * @return {Observable} a new observable with the Operator applied
     */
    lift<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R>;
    subscribe(observer?: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription;
    subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
    /** @deprecated This is an internal implementation detail, do not use. */
    _trySubscribe(sink: Subscriber<T>): TeardownLogic;
    /**
     * @method forEach
     * @param {Function} next a handler for each value emitted by the observable
     * @param {PromiseConstructor} [promiseCtor] a constructor function used to instantiate the Promise
     * @return {Promise} a promise that either resolves on observable completion or
     *  rejects with the handled error
     */
    forEach(next: (value: T) => void, promiseCtor?: PromiseConstructorLike): Promise<void>;
    /** @internal This is an internal implementation detail, do not use. */
    _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<any>): TeardownLogic;
    /**
     * @nocollapse
     * @deprecated In favor of iif creation function: import { iif } from 'rxjs';
     */
    static if: typeof iif;
    /**
     * @nocollapse
     * @deprecated In favor of throwError creation function: import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
     */
    static throw: typeof throwError;
    pipe(): Observable<T>;
    pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
    pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
    pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>): Observable<D>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>): Observable<E>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>): Observable<F>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>): Observable<G>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>): Observable<H>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>): Observable<I>;
    pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>, ...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<{}>;
    toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>): Promise<T>;
    toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>, PromiseCtor: typeof Promise): Promise<T>;
    toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>, PromiseCtor: PromiseConstructorLike): Promise<T>;
}
```

rx.extensions.ts

```
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export interface UiSignalData { uiLabel: string; debugInfo: string; }
export interface UiSignalSignature<T> {
    (label: string | UiSignalData): Observable<T>;
}
export interface FireAndForgetSignature {
    (): Subscription;
}
declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
    interface Observable<T> {
        uiSignal: UiSignalSignature<T>;
        fireAndForget: FireAndForgetSignature;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do in that code ??

Comment: P.S. You don't have to provide the definition file for `Observable`.

Comment: Could you show us the method definition for `uiSignal`?

Answer (score 2):

I have no clue what you are trying to achieve with that `uiSignal` call... However, the declaration clearly states that `uiSignal` is a static method on the `Observable` class (`static uiSignal: () => any;`). You are trying to invoke the static method from an instance of the class - TS does not allow that.

Also, the extension declaration replaces the rxjs module declaration. So then if you import the module using your extensions, it will not have the default Observable implementation - and vice versa - importing the Observable from the original module will not have your extensions.

Lastly, the Observable class is exported as a part of `rxjs` module, not `rxjs/Observable` in the new version.

If you want to have some side effects in the new rxjs pipe world, you can write either

```ts
this._runsProxy.manageShares(/*...*/).pipe(
  tap(value => /* do what you need to do */),
  // ...
)
```

Or implement your own operator if this is a recurring theme

```ts
const uiSignal = config =>
  pipe(
    tap(value => /* do something with the config and the pass-through value */),
    // any other pipeable operators you fancy
  );

this._runsProxy.manageShares(/*...*/).pipe(
  uiSignal(someConfig),
  // ...
)
```

Hope this helps a little :-)